# How to access the audio of call manager

Tags: android, audio, call

I would like to access the audio that my call manager captures while a call is active.
I would like to access it before it is transmitted to the other party.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, in-call audio is not available to Android applications.